# Set 'Load in QGIS' of all batch processing rows to 'no'?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, batch

I'm using 'Save Selected Features' algorithm from the Processing Toolbox.

I'm batch processing thousands of GeoJSON files to tab files but the same would be true for any conversion.  I've created a JSON input file to load in my thousands of records to convert, but QGIS opens each record created to the map view and therefore consumes all my system memory.

Is there a way to set all the rows to no without manually changing each, row by row?

[image]

Comment: You can set QGIS to not display layers when added: Settings > Options > Rendering.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @csk thanks - it still maps the output of the batch process though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Just manually set the first ***No*** value and then double-click on the `Load in QGIS` field name: it will set all the other rows to *No*.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292890/lecos-batch-processing-is-there-an-easier-way/292895#292895 for additional options if doing batch processing with more parameters that need to be changed.